# Sum over top_hits aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Question in short: if I have an aggregation for a top_hits per bucket, how do I sum a specific value in the resulting structure?

Details:

I have a number of records that contain per store a certain quantity. I want to get the sum of all latest record per store.

To get the latest record per store, I create the following aggregation:

```
"latest_quantity_per_store": {
    "aggs": {
        "latest_quantity": {
            "top_hits": {
                "sort": [
                    {
                        "datetime": "desc"
                    },
                    {
                        "quantity": "asc"
                    }
                ],
                "_source": {
                    "includes": [
                        "quantity"
                    ]
                },
                "size": 1
            }
        }
    },
    "terms": {
        "field": "store",
        "size": 10000
    }
}
```

Suppose I have two stores, and two quantities per store for two different timestamps. This is the result of that aggregation:

```
"latest_quantity_per_store": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": [
        {
            "key": "01",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "latest_quantity": {
                "hits": {
                    "total": 2,
                    "max_score": null,
                    "hits": [
                        {
                            "_index": "inventory-local",
                            "_type": "doc",
                            "_id": "O6wFD2UBG8e7nvSU8dYg",
                            "_score": null,
                            "_source": {
                                "quantity": 6
                            },
                            "sort": [
                                1532476800000,
                                6
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "02",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "latest_quantity": {
                "hits": {
                    "total": 2,
                    "max_score": null,
                    "hits": [
                        {
                            "_index": "inventory-local",
                            "_type": "doc",
                            "_id": "pLUFD2UBHBuSGcoH0ZT4",
                            "_score": null,
                            "_source": {
                                "quantity": 11
                            },
                            "sort": [
                                1532476800000,
                                11
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I now want to have an aggregation in ElasticSearch that takes the sum over these buckets. In the example data, the sum over 6 and 11. I tried the following aggregation:

```
"latest_quantity": {
    "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "latest_quantity_per_store>latest_quantity>hits>hits>_source>quantity"
    }
}
```

But this results in this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "No aggregation [hits] found for path [latest_quantity_per_store>latest_quantity>hits>hits>_source>quantity]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "inventory-local",
        "node": "3z5CqmmAQ-yT2sUCb69DzA",
        "reason": {
          "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason": "No aggregation [hits] found for path [latest_quantity_per_store>latest_quantity>hits>hits>_source>quantity]"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

**What would be the correct aggregation to get somehow the number 17 back from ElasticSearch?**

I did something similar for another aggregation that I had, an average instead of a top_hits aggregation.

```
"average_quantity": {
    "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "average_quantity_per_store>average_quantity"
    }
},
"average_quantity_per_store": {
    "aggs": {
        "average_quantity": {
            "avg": {
                "field": "quantity"
            }
        }
    },
    "terms": {
        "field": "store",
        "size": 10000
    }
}
```

This works as expected, this is the result:

```
"average_quantity_per_store": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": [
        {
            "key": "01",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "average_quantity": {
                "value": 6
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "02",
            "doc_count": 2,
            "average_quantity": {
                "value": 11.5
            }
        }
    ]
},
"average_quantity": {
    "value": 17.5
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a way to solve this using a mix of [`scripted_metric`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) aggregation and [`sum_bucket`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html) pipeline aggregation. The scripted metric aggregation is a bit complex, but to the main idea is to allow you to provide your own bucketing algorithm and spit out a single metric figure out of it.

In your case, what you want to do is to figure out the latest quantity for each store and then sum those store quantities. The solution looks like this, I'll explain some details below:

```
POST inventory-local/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "bystore": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "store.keyword",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest_quantity": {
          "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script": "params._agg.quantities = new TreeMap()",
            "map_script": "params._agg.quantities.put(doc.datetime.date, [doc.datetime.date.millis, doc.quantity.value])",
            "combine_script": "return params._agg.quantities.lastEntry().getValue()",
            "reduce_script": "def maxkey = 0; def qty = 0; for (a in params._aggs) {def currentKey = a[0]; if (currentKey > maxkey) {maxkey = currentKey; qty = a[1]} } return qty;"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sum_latest_quantities": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "bystore>latest_quantity.value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that in order for this to work, you need to set `script.painless.regex.enabled: true` in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file.

The `init_script` creates a `TreeMap` for each shard.
The `map_script` populates the `TreeMap` on each shard with mappings of date/quantities. The value that we put in the map contains the timestamp and the quantity in a single string. We'll need that timestamp later in the `reduce_script`.
The `combine_script` simply takes the last value of the `TreeMap` since this is the latest quantity for the given shard.
The bulk of the work is located in the `reduce_script`. We iterate all latest quantities for each shard and return the latest one.

At this point, we have the latest quantity for each store. All what remains to be done is to use a `sum_bucket` pipeline aggregation in order to sum each store quantity. And there you have the result of 17.

The response looks like this:

```
 "aggregations": {
    "bystore": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "01",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "latest_quantity": {
            "value": 6
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "02",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "latest_quantity": {
            "value": 11
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "sum_latest_quantities": {
      "value": 17
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can change the `elasticsearch.yml` file on an AWS hosted ElasticSearch domain?

Comment: Hmmm, good question. Not sure you can actually. I know there are a few whitelisted settings you can set, but unsure about whether AWS allows to change this one. You should consider migrating to [ES Cloud](https://www.elastic.co/blog/hosted-elasticsearch-services-roundup-elastic-cloud-and-amazon-elasticsearch-service) instead (backed by AWS as well but much more flexible)

Comment: Thanks for the link! In the meantime, I have asked the same question of changing the setting on the AWS forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=862576&#862576

Comment: And the answer is here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=856840&#856840 We can probably get away without using regexp for splitting that string, the problem is that [`String.split`is not whitelisted](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20952). I'll report in a moment...

Comment: I've updated my answer to simply use an array instead of a string. No need for split anymore.

Comment: That works! Thanks! Besides having my answer, I am glad I learned about Painless scripting language.

Comment: Remove the warning on the answer about changing the config? That confused me for a min as I was looking for a regex that wasn't in the scripts. :)