# How to get last entry for each distinct value of a field in Grafana with an Elasticsearch data source

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I have an elasticsearch index with documents like these :

```json
{
  "_source": {
    "category": 1,
    "value": 10,
    "utctimestamp": "2020-10-21T15:32:00.000+00:00"
  }
}
```

In Grafana, I'm able to retrive the value of the most recent event with the following query:

[image]

Now, I would like to get the MAX value of the most recent documents for each distinct value of `category` in the given time range.
This means that if I have the 3 following documents in my index :

```json
{
  "_source": {
    "category": 1,
    "value": 10,
    "utctimestamp": "2020-10-21T10:30:00"
  }
},
{
  "_source": {
    "category": 2,
    "value": 20,
    "utctimestamp": "2020-10-21T10:20:00"
  }
},
{
  "_source": {
    "category": 2,
    "value": 30,
    "utctimestamp": "2020-10-21T10:10:00"
  }
}
```

I would like the query to return the value MAX(10, 20) which is 20. Because the last document for category 1 has the value 10, and the last document for category 2 has the value 20. (If there were a 3rd category, its last value should also be included in the MAX).

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a middleware service with a REST API between Elasticsearch and Grafana that can make all the custom requests to Elasticsearch (like the request given in the answer of @saeednasehi), and I query the middleware from Grafana with the [JSON data source plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/simpod-json-datasource)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @val for his brilliant query in [Sum over top_hits aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709347/sum-over-top-hits-aggregation), your query would be something like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "category": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest_quantity": {
          "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script": "params._agg.quantities = new TreeMap()",
            "map_script": "params._agg.quantities.put(doc.utctimestamp.date, [doc.utctimestamp.date.millis, doc.value.value])",
            "combine_script": "return params._agg.quantities.lastEntry().getValue()",
            "reduce_script": "def maxkey = 0; def qty = 0; for (a in params._aggs) {def currentKey = a[0]; if (currentKey > maxkey) {maxkey = currentKey; qty = a[1]} } return qty;"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "max_quantities": {
      "max_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "category>latest_quantity.value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I guess there is no way to replicate this query directly in the query builder of grafana? I would like to avoid creating another index (storing results of this query) which would duplicate data for the only purpose of plotting in grafana.

Comment: Oh! sorry. I didn't realize that you want this for your grafana. let me check!